# Example using observables as promises

Tags: reactive-extensions-js

Does anyone have an example of how RX observables can be used to help the look of asynchronos code?

I am looking for an alternative to promises and I would like to see how it is done in rx.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [promise library](https://github.com/darylteo/rxjava-promises) built on the top of rxJava. You may take a look of the source about how it is implemented.